# Drupal Commerce order admin page, order id

Tags: drupal, admin, commerce

I'm building a commerce site using **Drupal Commerce**. I've got it going very smoothly now but I've hit a dead end when I'm trying to create a module for **handling shipping information and sending it to the shipping company** for label printing.

The problem is, that I have created a new tab in an Order page,

```
admin/commerce/orders/order_id/printlabel
```

and I can access this page via a tab when I edit an order.

Now, I have no idea how I can pull the order_id number in the module. I have tried almost everything, entity_view, entity_metadata_wrapper, commerce_order.module API, but I have no idea how I can access the id and that is the key. When I get the ID, I can get the shipping information linked to it and I can send this data to the shipping company and save it.I also looked into the ways Commerce does things like combine Payment with Views but it seemed a bit too complicated for me to try so, I'm asking here. I can't get any answers on Drupal's own support forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope i got your question right.You created a custom menu admin/commerce/orders/*/printlabel where * is the order id of a particular order. You need the order id.

The simplest solution to it is getting it through the arguments or arg(). This is a function that drupal provides to get data from the arguments. For eg

if your url is www.xyz.com/admin/commerce/orders/0001/printlabel & you need order id i.e 0001 you can get it using  arg(3).

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I actually figured that out moments before you answered. It's funny how I always find these answers before anybody gets to answer ;)